# Is there a way to fetch all unique array values from a mongoose schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

All of my mongoose blog posts have a array of tags, is there a way to fetch all unique tags from those arrays?

Blog Schema Excerpt

```
{
...
  tags: {
    type: [{type:String,lowercase:true}],
    default: [],
    required: true
  }
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [distinct](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#distinct_distinct):

```
Post.distinct('tags', (err, result) => {
    if (err) ...;

    console.log('UNIQUE TAGS:', result);
});
```